# Crop image on left and right

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML ([Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pwnhmp5r/5/)):

```
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <em class="brand">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40?text=LOGO"/>
    </em>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="frame">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x400?text=Image to Crop" />
      </div>      
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Our Message</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  Main content
</main>
```

And correspondent CSS:

```
header {
  text-align: center;
}    
div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}    
em.brand img {
  display: block;  
}    
ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}    
ul.menu li {  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
}    
ul.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}    
em {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
}    
nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 0;
}    
.slides {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}    
.slide .frame img {  
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 -100px;  
}    
.slide .text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}    
.slide .text h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 8px;
 }     
.slide .text p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
 }     
 main {
   border: 1px solid red;
   font-size: 20px;
 }
```

Using media queries I need, sometimes, to adjust the image by cropping it on Left/Right or on Bottom/Top:

```
.slide .frame img {  
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 -100px;  
}
```

This does not change the image. It only changes it if I try Top/Bottom:

```
.slide .frame img {  
  width: 100%;
  margin: -100px 0;  
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up the negative margins to the image's container, and set the image width: 100%

```
.slides {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; // so the "negative" part is not visible
}
.slide .frame {
  margin: 0 -100px;
}    
.slide .frame img {  
  width: 100%;  
}
```

But maybe you should the image as a background and use the property `background-size: cover;` and `background-position: center;`

Comment: The reason why I am not using backgrund size and position is because this is a Slider and the title and text witll change with the slider image. so I wanted to grouo that content together. Does it make sense?

Comment: I guess that's an option. But I always prefere to make the texts text ( but I if its not a site that you want indexed by search engines..  I guess then it makes sense )